# ionic global variable using

Tags: global-variables, ionic4

I am new to ionic , so I am using global variable to recive the result in service.ts, but the problem is
I prinited out the result both in my ngOnit and also in service's function , I got what I want in service.ts's function so I think the function itself works but when I printed the results in ngOnit which used global vairable to print out the result , it showed undefined， I  wondered what the problem is?

```
export class OutcomePage implements OnInit {
 data: any;
 map;
 userlat;
 userlng;
 public placelat;
 public placelng;
 public pos;
 public userpos;
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router ,private zone: NgZone,private geolocation: Geolocation , private service : ControllerserviceService) { 
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(param=>{
     if(param && param.special){
       this.data = JSON.parse(param.special);
     }
   });
 }
```

```
ngOnInit(): void{
    this.pos = this.service.getdistance();
    //console.log(this.userlat);
    this.userpos = this.service.getpos();
    console.log(this.pos);
    console.log(this.userpos)
  }
```

```
getpos(){
    this.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },  (results, status)  => { 
      let pos;
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            //console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            pos = {
              lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
              lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
            };
            console.log(pos);
            return pos;
        }
    });
  }
```

After a few test , I narrowed the problem to this code test

```
getdistance(){
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      this.userpos = {
        lat: resp.coords.latitude,
        lng: resp.coords.longitude
      };
      console.log(this.userpos);
      //console.log(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(new google.maps.LatLng(userpos.lat, userpos.lng), new google.maps.LatLng(this.pos)));   
      //console.log(resp.coords.latitude);
    })
    console.log(this.userpos);
    return this.userpos;
  }
```

so the first console log showed the exact result I want , but the second one show "undefined" , I think that's where the problem is , but I can't figure it out

Comment: Did you try to call userpos from othe page?

Comment: yes,because I write the function at service and tried to catch the results through service , but I think the problem is at the above which userpos show different results at the same function

Comment: Put the return inside then( when the value was returned, and add catch and return null if error , and by that the result will be return since inside then values are being returned normally...

Comment: I tried this way but it won't work since when I write the return in then , It would not return at all , I don't know what the problem is , I tested it by write two return as console log, it only return the one  which is'nt in then

Comment: Then remove the return, there is no need for it... just when you assign this.userpos = {...} then userpos is being set, or you can remove .then from serviceand just right return this.gelocation.getCurrentPosition(); and in your page write this.servicename.getdistance().then((resp) => { and get your values in same page } and this way is better than yours in is the correct way to achieve your aim other than setting data in service and getting them each time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure no data will be transfared to other pages since inside getpos() you decalred let pos so it will save the variable in the decalred pos and not to public pos, in order to save it in publoc pos, you need to do this change:

```
getpos(){
    this.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },  (results, status)  => { 
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            //console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            this.pos = {
              lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
              lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
            };
            console.log(this.pos);
            return this.pos;
        }
    });
  }
```

Now the values should be binded to the public pos since we used this to point on it instead of decaring a new variable named pos.

Comment: I tried what you write, but I actually write the page at two ts , one is at the result.ts  i want to show , the other one is at  the service.ts , and the global variable is used on the main page . I edited my question , maybe you have a  different thought on the question , thanks anyway